# mod_rewrite based on dbm value

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for some assistance in writing a RewriteRule to act on a dbm value. I have a dbm file that contains a userid and either a home directory path or a url. http://www.domain.com/~userid would lookup the userid and either return a home directory like /home/userid or a url like http://www.userid.com. If a home directory is returned, the content is displayed. If a url is returned, I would like the client to be redirected. Running Apache 2.2, I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /etc/httpd/logs/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 4
RewriteMap homedir.dbm dbm:/var/www/data/homedir.dbm
RewriteCond ${homedir.dbm:$1|lookupfailed}      (.*)
RewriteCond %1                                  !lookupfailed
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]+)/(.*)$                    /%1/www/$2 [L]
RewriteCond ${homedir.dbm:$1|lookupfailed}      (.*)
RewriteCond %1                                  !lookupfailed
RewriteCond %1                                  !^http [NC]
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]+)$                         /~$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond ${homedir.dbm:$1|lookupfailed}      (.*)
RewriteCond %1                                  !lookupfailed
RewriteCond %1                                  ^http [NC]
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]+)$                         %1 [R]
```

The home directory part seems to be working but I must be missing something simple on the url redirect part. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Made a few minor tweaks and it appears to be working. If anyone sees anything wrong or a better way of doing it, please let me know.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog /etc/httpd/logs/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 4
RewriteMap homedir.dbm dbm:/var/www/data/homedir.dbm
RewriteCond ${homedir.dbm:$1|lookupfailed}      (.*)
RewriteCond %1                                  !lookupfailed
RewriteCond %1                                  !^http [NC]
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]+)/(.*)$                    /%1/www/$2 [L]
RewriteCond ${homedir.dbm:$1|lookupfailed}      (.*)
RewriteCond %1                                  !lookupfailed
RewriteCond %1                                  ^http [NC]
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]+)/(.*)$                    ${homedir.dbm:$1} [L,R]
RewriteCond ${homedir.dbm:$1|lookupfailed}      (.*)
RewriteCond %1                                  !lookupfailed
RewriteCond %1                                  !^http [NC]
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]+)$                         /~$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond ${homedir.dbm:$1|lookupfailed}      (.*)
RewriteCond %1                                  !lookupfailed
RewriteCond %1                                  ^http [NC]
RewriteRule ^/~([^/]+)$                         ${homedir.dbm:$1} [L,R]
```